# Unable to get a value from the key in Sendgrid template

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3, sendgrid-templates

I am trying to get a value and use it in sendgrid email template. The JSON looks like this.

"productskumapping" : {
"created/updated" : 2,
"failed" : 0
}

{{productskumapping.created/updated}} does not give any value in the email template. the macro is not replaced. But the macro must replace with 2. How to make this work? the slash character("/") is causing the issue. Please sugggest any solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

SendGrid uses handlebars style expressions to interpolate data. I just learned that [slashes were a deprecated way that handlebars the library used to navigate objects](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#path-expressions). I don't know if SendGrid uses that exact handlebars library internally, but I thought it was important.

I believe the way to get around a slash in a key, like you have, is to surround the key with square brackets instead. This is known as [literal segments](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#literal-segments) and would look like this for you:

```
{{productskumapping.[created/updated]}}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked!!. You just saved me from complex json transformation.

Comment: Brilliant! Can you mark the answer as correct so that others with this issue can see it helped?